# JS: mathematically decrease zoom value inside event-listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, gesture, addeventlistener

I'm doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dom = document.body,
        fs = 16,
        min = 16,
        max = 100,
        scale;

    dom.addEventListener("gesturechange", gestureChange, false);

    function gestureChange(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        scale = e.scale;
        fs = Math.round(fs*scale);

        if ( fs <= max && fs >= min )
            $('#element').css('width', fs+'px');

        if ( fs > max ) fs = max;
        if ( fs < min ) fs = min;
    }

});
```

So when I do a pinch/zoom-gesture on my iPhone the width of the `#element` increases.
`fs` is the value it`s increasing in. However right now the zooming and increase in with is happening way too fast. So as soon as I move my fingers just a little bit on my screen the increase in width is rather big.

I wonder how and if I can "multiply" (or whatever) the fs value by a certain amount so the entire experience is slowing down? I just want my zoom to happen way slower.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't think there is one right answer to this question, but last time I programmed something like this, dividing the distance between the fingers by the zoom factor by 1000 plus the base zoom factor (100) worked for me.

Comment: How did you calculate the distance between the fingers? Would you mind showing me your approach?

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply) Pythagoras Theorem does the trick: `var dist = ((p1x - p2x) * (p1x - p2x)) +
  ((p1y - p2y) * (p1y - p2y));`

Comment: and where do you get the points `p1` and `p2` from?

Comment: Those are the two finger coordinates: `var p1x = e.touches[0].clientX;
  var p1y = e.touches[0].clientY;
  
  var p2x = e.touches[1].clientX;
  var p2y = e.touches[1].clientY;`

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply your own scale factor to the whole scaling calculation:

```
var myScale = 5; // Test which value is best suited for your needs
fs = Math.round(fs*(scale/myScale));
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is, that this is somehow just changing the "starting point" of the conversion. When I zoom in now the increase in width is kind of "delayed". The resize of the `#element` seems sort of slower but it's not as smooth as I want the whole thing to be. I want the resizing to be translated one-to-one from my zoom-gesture to the object.

Comment: Have you tried a smaller value like 2? I just read that the value is likely to be between 0 and 2, so maybe the value is becoming to small to see a Difference in the beginning of the gesture.